# Set Excel Zoom from MATLAB using ActiveX

Tags: excel, matlab

By default the Excel zoom is 100% on all sheets.
I am trying to change the zoom of Sheet1 to 80% using ActiveX from MATLAB.

Here is the code I tried, it did not give any error but the zoom remains unchanged.

```
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
WB = Excel.Workbooks.Add;
Sheets = Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;
Sheet1 = Sheets.get('Item',1);
Sheet1.Activate;
Sheet1.PageSetup.Zoom = 80;
WB.SaveAs([pwd, '\test.xls'])
Excel.Quit();
```

Does the code miss something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to change the *display zoom* you are looking for this command:

```
Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80;
```

The `PageSetup` zoom applies when *printing* the worksheet.